# Is it possible to extract the instance type from the instantiable type?

Tags: typescript

```js
class ClassOne {
  property1 = true;
}

type Instantiable = { new(...args: any[]): ClassOne };
```

Is it possible to extract the `ClassOne` directly from the `Instantiable` type? If that's the case, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript provides a utility type called [`InstanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype). You can use it like this:

```
class ClassOne {
  property1 = true;
}

type Instantiable = { new(...args: any[]): ClassOne };

type T = InstanceType<Instantiable>;
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5QPIDsCm0DeAoa0AOATgPZ6oEAuAngIzQC805BArqgNxYC+WWVp0ASWQRyYZOQCWYAEYh0DDNDQB3ABQA6TWAIBzCAC5oYygG0AugEpD8SBBTpOHXpX4AVeoOGjkwVK5eoADxCImKSMnIAfBxAA)

Under the hood it uses the `infer` keyword within a conditional type:

```
type InstanceType<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => any> = T extends abstract new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any
```

## Further reading

- [Inferring Within Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types)